# Controller error trying to run application with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receiving an error when I try and run the application I am building with ruby on rails. I am getting the following error:

[image: Error I am receiving]

> ActionController::MissingExactTemplate (TestController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html):

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

My route.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'test/index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'test#index'
end
```

My index file:

```html
<h1>Test#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/test/index.html.erb</p>
```

I can see all the files I am referring to but don't understand this error. Can anyone shed some light on why I am getting this error?

Comment: What is the full name of the index file (with extensions) and where is it located ?

Comment: @Viktor the index file is named index.html.erb and is located in the sampleApp/views/test/index.html.erb

Comment: Are you sure you saved the index file with that content? An error like that could occur when there's no content inside the view

Answer (score 3):

I think that is happening because the naming does not follow Rails naming conventions. Controllers should be named with plural nouns.

Placed the controller in `app/controllers/tests_controller.rb` and name it `TestsController`. Store the index view in `app/views/tests/index.html.erb`.

Furthermore the `config/routes.rb` needs to follow that convention too:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'tests#index'
end
```